# Ordering data in R lattice levelplot

Tags: r, lattice, levelplot

I am trying to make a lattice levelplot and want my levels plotted in a specific order.

```
name1 name2 value
A a 1
A b 3
A c 2
B a 4
B b 1
B c 3
C a 1
C b 3
C c 4
```

so let's say that I want name1 vertically and sorted by ascending sum of values for name1. How would I go about doing that?

---

I think I'm getting somewhere - I need to re-order the levels it seems. Still haven't figured out the exact way to do it.

---

So I managed to change the levels - BUT the values didn't change! I am using levels(reorder()). Do I have to use factor?

Answer (score 2):

It is a little bit confusing what do you want, but I guess you want that your `levelplot` looks like a gradient ...

I create the z level using `cumsum` and `ave`

```
dat$o <- ave(dat$value,dat$name1,FUN=cumsum)
```

Then

```
library(latticeExtra)
levelplot(o~name2+name1,data=dat,
          panel = panel.levelplot.points,type = c("p", "g"), 
          aspect = "iso", 
          prepanel = prepanel.default.xyplot,
          cex=10)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make myself clear - I meant that I want the rows to be ordered by value of the (a) column. So the first (top left) point should be B,a because it has the largest value from all the (a) points.

Actually even the way to order the columns or raws could help - I may be able to figure out the rest.